# Why is the local directory shortcut not working?

Tags: python, file

It's been a while since I worked with python but I think this could be a python version issue. Basically, I keep getting the error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../Traces/'" every time I try to use the backslash path reference. It raises an error at both points in the program. This isn't my code to change so please help me troubleshoot the source of the problem.

```
from math import log2
import random
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
from cache_424_w import Cache

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        if sys.argv[1] == 'all':
            #breaks try block here
            files = os.listdir('../Traces/')
        else:
            files = [sys.argv[1]]
        cacheSize = int(sys.argv[2])
        ways = int(sys.argv[3])
        block_size = int(sys.argv[4])

    except:
        print('main.py trace cacheSize(Bytes) #ofWays blockSize(Bytes)')

    cache = Cache(cacheSize, ways, block_size)
    cache.reset()

    for file in files:
        print(file)

        cache.reset()
        compute = 0

        #causes error here
        with open('../Traces/{}'.format(file)) as f:
            trace = f.readlines()
```

Comment: What does os.getcwd() return?

Comment: I presume it's supposed to make a list of the files in that directory, but I'm not certain

Comment: As simple as it sounds, the most likely cause is that `../Traces` does not exist as the error suggests. Make sure that the file actually exists in relation to the current working directory of the python script., and also that you have read permissions on both the parent directory of the file and the file itself.

Comment: No, os.getcwd() returns the current working directory. It will tell you what path ../Traces does not exist relative to.